# What is the best strategy for the solitaire game Golf?

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, card-games

In Golf, 35 cards are dealt into seven face-up tableaux of five cards each, all of which are visible at once.  Then one card is dealt face-up to form the discard pile, and the remaining 16 cards are put in a face-down stack ("the stack").

On each turn, the player places a card face-up on top of the discard pile subject to the following rules, listed in decreasing order of precedence.  Call the topmost discard the "active card."

1. The top card of the stack may be discarded to form a new active card, regardless of the rank of the current active card.
2. No card may be discarded onto a King.
3. Only a 2 may be discarded onto an Ace.
4. A discard must be adjacent in rank to the active card.  For example, if the active card is a 7, then only a 6 or an 8 may be discarded.

The object of the game is to discard all 52 cards.

What is the best strategy for this game, and what per cent of games are winnable with perfect strategy?

Comment: I'm confused; what constitutes winning? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @Travis Combinatorics is not my area of expertise, so not much.  I found this game on an old computer and really just wanted to start a discussion.

Comment: You should make clear that rule $1$ does not depend on the card matching the existing active card as in rules $2-4$.  Essentially you turn the top card of the stack, put it on the discard pile, then discard as many cards according to rules $2-4$ as you wish.  You then turn the next card of the stack.  The game is won if you clear the tableau.  I doubt there is a concise best strategy.  The greedy one of play as much as you can on each card turned from the stack is probably not far wrong.

Comment: @RossMillikan A more interesting question is what to do when there are a few choices.  For example, given a few possible discards, which one should be chosen?  

A good, but unrigorous, answer is that you should prefer to discard Kings and Aces whenever possible, then prefer discards that will clear up cards adjacent to already-available cards.  For example, if there is a 5 on top of a tableau, a Jack as the active card, and you can choose to discard a Queen on top of a 6 or a 10 on top of, say, an 8, then you should choose the Queen.

Comment: @RossMillikan However, my last bit of "analysis" doesn't necessarily hold if there are Kings still in play.  For we might need Queens to discard those Kings.  So the question is how to choose which card to discard given competing smaller goals (eliminating Kings and making long runs of discards more likely).

Comment: @RossMillikan I agree with your comment and would add two wrinkles.  [1] The game is similar to blackjack card counting in that you know exactly what cards haven't surfaced yet, but not the order that they will appear.  [2] It *simultaneously* seems advantageous to try to plan long sequences, and to avoid greedy play if it disrupts that.  For example, if all you have left are one card each of the cards 2 thru king, and you know there is at least one ace or 3 remaining, just wait for one of those two cards.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks, I was confused about that.  I have therefore deleted my answer.

Comment: I agree with you about the complications, which is why I said the greedy approach is not far wrong.  I played it long ago and those choices are reasonably rare.  When you have one, it is often easy to see which will lead to clearing the most cards from the tableau.  I suspect the hard choices do not affect the winning rate much, but do not have a proof.